# How can I transform my DataFrame to normal distribution?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a Dataframe like this.

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [0.1,0.15,0.22,0.2], 'B' : [0.9,0.85,0.78,0.8]})
my_df
# normality test
stat, p = shapiro(my_df)
print('Statistics=%.3f, p=%.3f' % (stat, p))
```

The Shapiro test shows that the data is not Gaussian distribution.

How can I change my Data Frame so that it gets two new columns (i.e. four features with the existing two columns) with new values which follow a normal / Gaussian distribution?

Comment: Can you share expected output based on the sample input?

Comment: I don't quite understand. The new output should be new values that are calculated for the existing values in column A and B.

Comment: How new columns should be connected to non-normal existing ones?

Comment: This is what I don't know. I guess there are certain functions one can do to get normalized values.

Comment: Why not simply generate new normals?

Comment: Because this a just an example dataframe. In my original Data Frame there are actual values that are not normalized.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't use a StandardScaler?

Comment: How would that work?

Comment: @büşraçelik StandardScaler won't make data normal

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer.html @SergeyBushmanov does this work?

Comment: @büşraçelik No, it's different, it chages scale, but not the distribution

Answer (score 1):

Normalization of data is done with [`boxcox`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html) transformation, so you can do:

```
from scipy.stats import boxcox, shapiro
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [0.1,0.15,0.22,0.2], 'B' : [0.9,0.85,0.78,0.8]})
df_norm = my_df.apply(lambda x: boxcox(x)[0])
print(df_norm)
          A         B
0 -0.660612 -0.134124
1 -0.641490 -0.237600
2 -0.609405 -0.451641
3 -0.619138 -0.379958
```

Comment: Thanks. Can the values also be positive?

Comment: In my orginal Data Frame the p-Value is still 0 after normalizing it with your suggested boxcox function. What could I do?

Comment: Show your full data

Comment: For me it worked with PowerTransformer(method='yeo-johnson', standardize=True)